# Spark filters are never applied to DataFrame in Java

Tags: java, oracle, apache-spark, dataframe

I am very new with Spark, and I have a query that brings data from two Oracle tables. Such tables have to be joined by a field, which works fine with the code below. However, I need to apply filters as in an Oracle "where" clause. For example, bring employees whose age is between 25 and 50. I also have to apply GroupBy filters and sort the final results with OrderBy. The thing is that the only action that is performed correctly is the retrieval of all data from the tables and the join between them. The rest of the filters are simply not applied and I have no idea of why. Can you please help me out with this? I am sure I am missing something because NO compile errors are gotten. The data is loaded fine, but the "where" clauses seem not to be having any effect on the data, although there are Employees with age between 25 and 50. Many thanks!

```
public static JavaRDD<Row> getResultsFromQuery(String connectionUrl) {

    JavaSparkContext sparkContext = new JavaSparkContext(new SparkConf()
            .setAppName("SparkJdbcDs").setMaster("local"));
    SQLContext sqlContext = new SQLContext(sparkContext);

    Map<String, String> options = new HashMap<>();
    options.put("driver", "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
    options.put("url", connectionUrl);
    options.put("dbtable", "EMPLOYEE");

    DataFrameReader dataFrameReader = sqlContext.read().format("jdbc")
            .options(options);

    DataFrame dataFrameFirstTable = dataFrameReader.load();

    options.put("dbtable", "DEPARTMENT");

    dataFrameReader = sqlContext.read().format("jdbc").options(options);

    DataFrame dataFrameSecondTable = dataFrameReader.load();

    //JOIN. IT WORKS JUST FINE!!!

    DataFrame resultingDataFrame = dataFrameFirstTable.join(dataFrameSecondTable, 
            "DEPARTMENTID");


    //FILTERS. THEY DO NOT THROW ERROR, BUT ARE NOT APPLIED. RESULTS ARE ALWAYS THE SAME, WITHOUT FILTERS
    resultingDataFrame.where(resultingDataFrame.col("AGE").geq(25));
    resultingDataFrame.where(resultingDataFrame.col("AGE").leq(50));

    JavaRDD<Row> resultFromQuery = resultingDataFrame.toJavaRDD();

    //HERE I CONFIRM THAT THE NUMBER OF ROWS GOTTEN IS ALWAYS THE SAME, SO THE FILTERS DO NOT WORK.
    System.out.println("Number of rows "+resultFromQuery.count());

    return resultFromQuery;
```

}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`where` returns a new dataframe and does NOT alter the existing one, so you need to store the output:

```
DataFrame greaterThan25 = resultingDataFrame.where(resultingDataFrame.col("AGE").geq(25));
DataFrame lessThanGreaterThan = greaterThan25.where(resultingDataFrame.col("AGE").leq(50));
JavaRDD<Row> resultFromQuery = lessThanGreaterThan.toJavaRDD();
```

Or you can just chain it:

```
DataFrame resultingDataFrame = dataFrameFirstTable.join(dataFrameSecondTable, "DEPARTMENTID")
  .where(resultingDataFrame.col("AGE").geq(25))
  .where(resultingDataFrame.col("AGE").leq(50));
```

Comment: Justin, thank you very much for your answer! It did work for the AGE ranges. However, when I use .groupBy and try to do the same as to have the result in a DataFrame, it says that the data retrieved have to be stored in a GroupedData object, which works fine when I do it. The problem is that I do not know how to iterate such object or how to convert it into a JavaRDD<Row> that is what the method must return in the end. Do you or anybody else have any idea as to how to achieve this? I really thank you for your interest and help.

Comment: I attach the code that I am using to group the data:                `GroupedData  resultingGroupData =  lessThanGreaterThan.groupBy(resultingDataFrame.col("DEPARTMENT_NAME"));` //I apply the groupBy command
`System.out.println("Number of data gotten: "+resultingGroupData .count().count());` //here I confirm that it gets 5 groups, which are the number of departments that exist in the DB

Comment: The methods you have available to you can be found in the docs. https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.GroupedData You probably want to use agg. Or, you can drop down to an RDD and use THAT groupBy, which returns a RDD[(K,Iterable)]

Comment: Thanks a bunch, Justin! You helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

```
people.select("person_id", "first_name").filter(people("person_id") == 2).show
```

It won't work and you'll be getting the Following Error:

> Error: overloaded method value filter with alternatives:
>   (conditionExpr: String)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame 
>   (condition: org.apache.spark.sql.Column)
>   org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame cannot be applied to (Boolean)

**It seems that, to work with Select clauses in Spark dataframe along with filter, we can't pass Boolean.**

These two queries are used to select single row from Spark DataFrame with two different clauses, where and filter.

```
people.select("person_id", "first_name").filter(people("person_id") === 2).show

people.select("person_id", "first_name").where(people("person_id") === 2).show
```

Use one of the above query, to select single row from Spark DataFrame.